# How do I use preferences on fragments with ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, android-viewpager

I am using ViewPager to swipe through different fragments. It is working but now I want to add settings for each fragment as you can do with Activities in this way:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
}
```

But when I put `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);` in my Fragment Eclipse tells me `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);` doesn't exist, the same if I use FragmentActivity. So, how do I use preferences in fragments? 
I am new at designing with Fragments and everything is pretty much different compared to how you do in Activities :/

Thank you :)

**==EDIT==**

I am not getting a FC but it does nothing, it is the code which calls class LCprefs(), this code is on a Fragment:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)");
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.preferences:
            new LCprefs();
            break;
        case R.id.add:
            break;
        case R.id.load:
            break;
        case R.id.save:
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

It is LCprefs class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.util.Log;

    public class LCprefs extends PreferenceFragment{

        String TAG;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.i(TAG, "LCprefs onCreate()");
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefslc);
        }

    }
```

It is prefslc.xml located on xml folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Varios" >

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="cbFullscreen"
            android:summary="Aplicacion fullscreen"
            android:title="Fullscreen" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 1):

The fragment needs to be an instance of [PreferencesFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html). Example from the link:

```
public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot just create a new fragment like that. You need to add it to the view too, or build a new activity around it.